# Can isabelle unfold definitions with explicit type?

Tags: class, types, isabelle

I have defined  directed sets but need to apply the definition to both "'a set" and "'a set set"  in the same lemma. This seems to work fine. But both  "apply (unfold directed_def)" and "apply(simp add: directed_def) only unfold the definition of directed  with type "'a set" the definition of directed with type "'a set set" is not unfolded. (Example proof is striped of any value and just used to demonstrate the problem)

Is there any way to unfold definition instances that have distinct type?

```
theory Scratch imports  "HOL-Lattice.Bounds" 
begin
instantiation  set:: (type)  partial_order
begin
definition setpoDef: "a⊑(b:: 'a set) = subset_eq a  b"
instance proof 
   fix x::"'a set"     show " x ⊑ x" by (auto simp: setpoDef) 
  fix x y z::"'a set" show  "x ⊑ y ⟹ y ⊑ z ⟹ x ⊑ z" by (auto simp: setpoDef)
  fix x y::"'a set" show "x ⊑ y ⟹ y ⊑ x ⟹ x = y"   by (auto simp: setpoDef)
qed     
end
context partial_order begin 
definition directed:: "'a  set ⇒ bool" where
 " directed D  ≡ 
    ¬D={} ∧ ( ∀ a1 a2. a1∈D∧ a2∈D ⟶ (∃ ub∈D . (a1⊑ ub ∧ a2⊑ ub))) " (* page 120 *)

lemma " ((directed:: 'a set set ⇒ bool) D)   ⟹ directed (⋃ D)"
  apply (simp add:  directed_def ) (* ** *)
  apply(unfold  directed_def )   
end
end
```

> Output at (* ** *)

```
(directed D ⟹ (∃x∈D. x ≠ {}) ∧ (∀a1 a2. (∃X∈D. a1 ∈ X) ∧ (∃X∈D. a2 ∈ X) ⟶ (∃y∈D. ∃ub∈y. a1 ⊑ ub ∧ a2 ⊑ ub))
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the context of a type class like `partial_order`, the type variable `'a` is fixed. It represents the instantiating type of the type class. Accordingly, the definition of `directed` is monomorphic inside the `partial_order` context. Your lemma, however, involves two different instances of the type class: `'a set` and `'a`. It therefore does not make sense to state it inside the type class context.

If you move it out of the `partial_order` context, both `simp` and `unfold` should act on both occurrences of `directed`.